Install Pre-compiled binaries on Google Colab
I want to install pre-compiled binaries on Google colab (this script: https://github.com/PaoloRibeca/TheTransporter). I have put it in /content/app/TheTransporter-main and set path as follows:
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/app/TheTransporter-main')

But Colab shows the following error when I run the command !TheTransporter --version:

/bin/bash: line 1: TheTransporter: command not found

Could anyone help me fix the issue?

Instead of using sys.path.append you can directly navigate using %cd. This approach is simpler and keeps the code cleaner:
%cd App/TheTransporter-main/
!./TheTransporter --version

(In a single code block)
